# Unable to count non-match rows as NULL from JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query joining two "fake" tables:

```
select count(tb2.col2) from (select unnest(array['A','B']) col1) tb1 left join (select unnest(array['B','C']) col2) tb2 on tb1.col1=tb2.col2 where tb2.col2 IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/22712

You can see that I expect the count of NULL to be `1` but it shows `0`

So how to count the non-match rows?

```
 col1 | col2
------+------
 A    |
 B    | B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select count(*)` instead of `select count(tb2.col2)`.

- `count(*)` is the number of rows.
- `count(expr)` is the number of rows where `expr` is non-null.

Comment: I wanted to count non-match (aka NULL), not the other way around.

Comment: But that's what `count(*)` does. You're already filtering by `where tb2.col2 IS NULL`.

Comment: @jspcal is correct. the count(*) simply references the row count. Any function applied directly against a 'NULL' column will fail.  His approach is correct.

Comment: The other way to do this is to make a column like 
CASE WHEN my_column IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
which can be SUM'd